# update the database column value based on check box checked in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to update the database column value based on check box checked in grid view using asp.net c#

In below coding, chbox showing null reference exception

```
foreach (GridViewRow rows in grdApproval.Rows)
{                

       if (Chbox.Checked)
       {
            int RoleID = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["RoleID"].ToString());
            int TsId = Convert.ToInt32(hfTimesheetId.Value);
            var Qry = (from m1 in TSEntity.Roles
                       where m1.RoleId == RoleID
                       select m1).FirstOrDefault();
            if (Qry != null)
            {
                  var QryEditTimesheet = (from m2 in TSEntity.TimeSheets
                                          where m2.Id == TsId
                                          select m2).FirstOrDefault();
                  if (QryEditTimesheet != null)
                  {
                        QryEditTimesheet.IsApproved = true;
                        QryEditTimesheet.ApprovedBy = ViewState["EmpName"].ToString();
                        QryEditTimesheet.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                        TSEntity.SaveChanges();
                  }
            }
            BindGrid();


       }
       else
       {
            BindGrid();
       }
}
```

Comment: show your html code as well as how you delcare chbox

Comment: Only thing I could say seeing this is do a `null` check.

Comment: You have to find your `CheckBox` first, then cast it as `CheckBox` as `(CheckBox)row.FindControl("your_checkbox_id")`

Answer (score 0):

without any further information, i can just guess.

first i would recommend to change your first line to

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in grdApproval.Rows)
```

and second can you try to change your second line to

```
if(row.Columns["yourcheckboxcolumnnumber"].checked)
```

hope that helps.

Comment: There may be possibility of the presence of `CheckBox` control also. Then your second line won't work.